# C++ AVL Tree Deletion

Tags: c++

So, I want to take input from a text file, then do some operations in an AVL tree. I could implement insertion, yet I can't build a solution for deletion in my mind. Can you help me? Here is the code.

```
 #include<iostream>
 #include<cstdio>
 #include<sstream>
 #include<algorithm>
 #include <fstream>
 #include <stdlib.h>
 #include <array>
 #include <ctime>

  using namespace std;

  struct node
  {
      int data;
      int height;
      struct node *leftchild;
      struct node *rightchild;

  }*root;

 class avlTree
  {
      public:
      int height(node *);
      int difference(node *);
      node *rrtraversal(node *);
      node *lltraversal(node *);
      node *lrtraversal(node *);
      node *rltraversal(node *);
      node* balance(node *);
      node* insert(node *, int );
      void display(node *, int);
      node *del(node *, int);

      avlTree()
      {
        root = NULL;
      }
 };

int avlTree::height(node *temp)
{
    int h = 0;
    if (temp != NULL)
    {
        int l_height = height (temp->leftchild);
        int r_height = height (temp->rightchild);
        int max_height = max (l_height, r_height);
        h = max_height + 1;
    }
    return h;
}

int avlTree::difference(node *temp)
{
    int l_height = height (temp->leftchild);
    int r_height = height (temp->rightchild);
    int b_factor= l_height - r_height;
    return b_factor;
}

node *avlTree::rrtraversal(node *parent)
{
    node *temp;
    temp = parent->rightchild;
    parent->rightchild = temp->leftchild;
    temp->leftchild = parent;
    return temp;
}

node *avlTree::lltraversal(node *parent)
{
    node *temp;
    temp = parent->leftchild;
    parent->leftchild = temp->rightchild;
    temp->rightchild = parent;
    return temp;
}

node *avlTree::lrtraversal(node *parent)
{
    node *temp;
    temp = parent->leftchild;
    parent->leftchild = rrtraversal (temp);
    return lltraversal (parent);
}


node *avlTree::rltraversal(node *parent)
{
    node *temp;
    temp = parent->rightchild;
    parent->rightchild = lltraversal (temp);
    return rrtraversal (parent);
}


 node *avlTree::balance(node *temp)
{
    int bal_factor = difference (temp);
    if (bal_factor > 1)
    {
        if (difference (temp->leftchild) > 0)
            temp = lltraversal (temp);
        else
            temp = lrtraversal (temp);
    }
    else if (bal_factor < -1)
    {
        if (difference (temp->rightchild) > 0)
            temp = rltraversal (temp);
        else
            temp = rrtraversal (temp);
    }
    return temp;
}


node *avlTree::insert(node *root, int value)
{
    if (root == NULL)
    {
        root = new node;
        root->data = value;
        root->leftchild = NULL;
        root->rightchild = NULL;
        return root;
    }
    else if (value < root->data)
    {
        root->leftchild = insert(root->leftchild, value);
        root = balance (root);
    }
    else if (value >= root->data)
    {
        root->rightchild = insert(root->rightchild, value);
        root = balance (root);
    }
    return root;
}

void avlTree::display(node *ptr, int level)
{
    int i;
    if (ptr!=NULL)
    {
        display(ptr->rightchild, level + 1);
        printf("\n");
        for (i = 0; i < level && ptr != root; i++)
            cout<<"        ";
        cout<<ptr->data;
        display(ptr->leftchild, level + 1);
    }
}

node *avlTree::del(node *root, int x)
{
    node *d;

    if ( x < root->data){
        del(root->leftchild,x);

    }
    else if (x > root->data){
        del(root->rightchild,x);


    }
    else if ((root->leftchild == NULL) && (root->rightchild == NULL))
    {
        d=root;
        free(d);
        root=NULL;

    }
    else if (root->leftchild == NULL)
    {
        d=root;
        free(d);
        root= root->rightchild;

    }
    else if (root->rightchild == NULL)
    {
        d=root;
        root=root->leftchild;
        free(d);

    }

    return root;

}

int main()
{

    ifstream myFile("file.txt");
    int a = 0;
    std::array<string,512> arrayTest;
    int index = 0;
    string content;
    avlTree avl;

    while (myFile >> content){
        arrayTest[index] = content;
        index++;    
    }

    clock_t startTime = clock();

    for(a = 0; a < arrayTest.size();a++){
        if(arrayTest[a] == "i"){
        root = avl.insert(root, std::stoi(arrayTest[a+1]));
        }
    }

    avl.display(root,1);

    clock_t endTime = clock();
    clock_t clockTicksTaken = endTime - startTime;
    double timeInSeconds = clockTicksTaken / (double) CLOCKS_PER_SEC;

    cout << "\n\n" << timeInSeconds << " secs\n";

}
```

In file, the content is like this. i 1 i 2 i 3 i 4 i 5 d 3

If program sees i, it will do an insert operation. Likewise, if it sees d, it will do a delete operation.

Comment: Is del() your first attempt ? Why didn't you use balance() therein ? And why do you free() nodes instead of delete-ing them ?

Comment: I found a code in internet and was simply trying to understand about what to do or how to implement an efficient delete operation in my code. I tried to do balance() in the code but it gives me .exe stopped working problem in whatever I tried to do. And without balance it gives me wrong output.

Comment: Draw the tree on a piece of paper. Then put a cross on a node and look at how you have to change its parent and childs links to ignore/avoid the node to delete while keeping the ordering logic. This will make clear how to change pointers before deleting the node.

Answer (score -1):

Did you try free() function?

```
free(node);
```

Comment: Yes I did but whenever I try to display my tree it gives me "Stopped working" error.

Comment: remove the link to the node and try free(node) like:root->rightnode = NULL; and then free(node).

Comment: No: when nodes are created with new they have to be deleted with delete. Mixing new with free is not correct because free does not call the destructor and it is not guaranteed tha free store and heap are the same (i.e. Could work with some implementations and fail with others).